# CrystalReports: If/Else statement displaying one side of results

Tags: crystal-reports, openedge, progress-db

I am attempting to create a report in crystal which has a weight which varies based upon our WMS database.
I have two separate tables I need to pull from where one has a yes/no for an item definition and this table also has weight for the items, and the other table has catch weights for items without defined weights.

I am attempting to have one formula either pull the weight for an item and multiply it by the cases per pallet or if the item has a catch weight (scanned weights individually per pallet), display the catch weight.

Where the weight for the item defintion is {WITEMUOM1.WEIGHT},

The quantity of cases per pallet is {WINVENTORY.QTYONHAND},

and the sum of case catch weights on the pallet is {#TOT PACK CW WEIGHT}

Below is an example of one of the formulas I have attempted to use and none net me a usable result.

The issue I am having is that it seems to be culling one half of the 'boolean' results; if I set the if statement for catch weights to = NO, the formula is culling all non-catch weight results and if I set it =YES, I get the same result, the if/then is not working and seems to just be reading only the else statement and only displaying it's results.

```
IF {WITEM.CATCHWEIGHT} = NO THEN ({WINVENTORY.QTYONHAND} * {WITEMUOM1.WEIGHT})
     ELSE {#TOT PACK CW WEIGHT}
```

Basically, I want the formula to read:

({wInventory.QtyOnHand} * {wItemUOM1.Weight}) if catchweight = no, and

{#TOT PACK CW WEIGHT} if catchweight = yes.

For whatever reason I cannot figure out how to get this output both results regardless of how I phrase the formula and how much googling I do.

Help would be extremely appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using {WITEM.CATCHWEIGHT} wrong. From what you posted I think it's a boolean. So you should try something like that:

`IF NOT {WITEM.CATCHWEIGHT} THEN ({WINVENTORY.QTYONHAND} * {WITEMUOM1.WEIGHT}) ELSE {#TOT PACK CW WEIGHT}`